# Unable to load asset: Image

Tags: list, flutter, image, dart, flutter-image

I have this code for asset image

```
 Image.asset(
              '${listPic[1]}',
           
            ),
```

the images are located in a List
`final List<Image> listPic= <Image>[ Image.asset('assets/images/pic1.jpg'), Image.asset('assets/images/pic2.jpg'), ];`

I know the pubsec works, because when I directly type the image location like this

```
Image.asset(
              'assets/images/pic1.jpg',
            ),
```

the image is displayed,
Is there something wrong with the list or Image.asset()
I have tried using .toString after the ${listPic[0]} it didn't do anything instead said unnecessary string interpolation.

gives this error

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: Unable to load asset: Image(image: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/pic1.jpg"), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: Alignment.center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list you declared is a `List<Image>` type, but you are using it as if it's a `List<String>`.

Try this instead:

```
final List<String> imagePaths = [ 
    'your/path/pic1.jpg', 
    'your/path/pic2.jpg',
];
```

---

```
Image.asset(
    toolImage[1],
)
```

Comment: aha thank you!. This was such a stupid error..my head was spinning xd

Comment: can you please edit the image path..don't want it to show up as plagiarism xd :>